# "Would be" in a conditional sentence

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

I heard this sentence in a series.

> I would be a fan of your work if you could get us two seats on the
> next flight.

What is the conditional type of this sentence?

Comment: Syntactically speaking it's a *slightly* unusual context. The addressee might be quite ***capable*** of getting those two seats for the speaker - but if he didn't ***actually*** do this obviously the speaker wouldn't become a fan. So strictly it should probably be *I **will** be a fan ... if you **get** us two seats...* But colloquially speaking, it's perfectly normal for a "deferential supplicant" like this to use more "indirect" verb forms (***could you, can you*** rather than "blunt, forthright" ***will you***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could this be made into an answer? I'm going through some of the unanswered questions list.